# Reuse Windows XP updates

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update

Can I use the windows XP updates that are installed on one computer (hard drive) on another?

I could put the hard drive in a enclosure and then drag the whole folder over to the new system via the USB port?

Or do I have to download everything all over again?

Comment: Also, [search this site](http://superuser.com/search?q=wsus) for questions where Windows Server Update Services was already discussed .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transferring Windows Updates from one machine to another is not supported and, as said, a really bad idea. Many patches do behave differently on different plattforms. There is no (supported) possibility to copy a 'patched' system to another machine. You can, however, copy the pre-patch state of your files ($KB* in %SystemRoot% for XP or %SystemRoot%\WinSxS for vista and higher).
If you need those updates as an offline package (for multi machine use for example or if you have a slow internet connection), give http://www.wsusoffline.net/ a try; these guys are maintaining a script, that does the windows update for you but stores all the patches for offline usage.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [WSUS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Server_Update_Services) (Windows Server Update Services). It enables system administrators to distribute Windows Updates inside the local network, so there is no necessity for every single computer to download updates separately.

Article says it should be running on Windows Server. I am not Windows guy at all so I do not know if you can run this thing on regular Windows XP system.

Answer (score 1):

That would be a **REAL BAD** idea. Each computer is unique. They have different hardware, software, releases, etc.

Comment: No... it is the same exact computer and software. But it is a new hard drive and the new one needs the updates that are already on the old one.

Comment: "No... it is the same exact computer and software." That is pretty much impossible, even different releases of hard disks (which you mentioned) will need different drivers.